# 10.1.3 Guess the Word, Part 2 Help Needed

Tags: python

I am currently stuck on exercise 10.1.3 on CodeHS, which is essentially a part in making a hangman game, without the hangman. I have my code nearly complete for this section of the game, yet for some reason whenever new input is given (for a letter), it clears previous input.

Here is my code:

```
secret_word = "character"
dashes = "-" * len(secret_word)
print(dashes)
#Prints the first row of dashes to indicate word length

def get_guess():
    while True:
        guess = input("Guess: ")
        if isinstance(guess, int):
            print("Your guess must be a lowercase letter.")
        else:
            if guess.islower():
                if len(guess) == 1:
                    return guess
                else:
                    print("Your guess must have exactly one character.")

def update_dashes(secret_word, dashes, guess):
    result = ""
    for i in range(len(secret_word)):
        if secret_word[i] == guess:
            result = result[:i] + guess + result[i + 1:]
        else:
            result = result + "-"
    return result

while True:
    guess = get_guess()
    if guess in secret_word:
        print("The letter is in the word.")
    else:
        print("That letter is not in the word.")
    print(update_dashes(secret_word, dashes, guess))
#We believe the issue is here, it is printing the full set each time this loops.
```

When run, this is the output:

```
---------
Guess: c
The letter is in the word.
c----c---
Guess: h
The letter is in the word.
-h-------
Guess:
```

The code should be adding the "h" to the word, yet it is 'overwriting' what is already there.

This is what I want it to print:

```
---------
Guess: c
The letter is in the word.
c----c---
Guess: h
The letter is in the word.
ch---c---
Guess:
```

Note that the word that should be guessed is "character".

And finally, this is the part of the assignment that relates to what the current problem is:

> **Step 2 - Update the Dashes**
>
> Here’s the tricky part. Write a function called update_dashes that
> takes three string arguments - the secret word, the current state of
> dashes, and the most recent guess - and returns the new state of
> dashes.
>
> So, for example, if the word is "eggplant", the current value of
> dashes is "e-------", and the guess is "g", the function should return
> "egg-----".
>
> If the word is "eggplant", the current value of dashes is "e-------",
> and the guess is "z", the function should return "e-------" (nothing
> changes, since the guess was incorrect).
>
> Here’s how you might go about this.
>
> In your function, start with an empty result string. Write a for loop
> from 0 up to but not including the length of your secret word. Say you
> use the variable i in your for loop. Compare the character in
> secret_word at index i to the guess. If they’re equal, then that means
> the guess matches that letter in the word, so you should add the guess
> to the result. Otherwise, the guess does not match that letter in the
> word, so you should add whatever was at index i in dashes to your
> result.
>
> *Wait, why don’t I just add a dash in the second case?*
>
> If you just add a dash whenever the guess doesn’t match the character
> in secret_word at index i, that will wipe out any correct guesses the
> user has already made! Imagine the case where the word is “eggplant”,
> the state of dashes is “e——-“, and the guess is “g”. If you always add
> a dash when the guess doesn’t match the character in secret_word at
> index i, the result would be “-gg—–”. Suddenly, the “e” is gone,
> because “g” did not match “e”! By instead using dashes at index i, you
> might append either a letter or a dash, depending on whether or not
> the user had already guessed that letter prior to the current guess.
>
> Once your for loop is done, your result string should have letters and
> dashes in all the right places, so you can just return it!

Comment: `input()` always returns a string, so `isinstance(guess, int)` will never be true.

Comment: You're doing exactly what it says you shouldn't do in "Why don't I just add a dash in the second case?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the instructions say, when the guess doesn't match you should add the corresponding element of `dashes` to the result, not just a dash. You need to do this so that all the previous correct guesses are copied to the result.

```
def update_dashes(secret_word, dashes, guess):
    result = ""
    for i in range(len(secret_word)):
        if secret_word[i] == guess:
            result += guess
        else:
            result += dashes[i]
    return result
```

Additionally, your main loop has to assign the result back to `dashes` so it accumulates all the correct guesses.

```
while True:
    guess = get_guess()
    if guess in secret_word:
        print("The letter is in the word.")
        dashes = update_dashes(secret_word, dashes, guess)
    else:
        print("That letter is not in the word.")
    print(dashes)
```